# Full-width page on free wordpress.com site

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a [site](https://wordpress.com/customize/unclejerry9466728.wordpress.com) hosted on wordpress.com, free tier. As such I don't have access to CSS. I'd like to make the page full-width but don't find any controls for such. Is this possible?

For example [this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-full-width-page-in-wordpress/) site refers to controls not seen in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free plan doesn't have access to "customization" options (see [wordpress.com plans comparison](https://wordpress.com/pricing/) for more details) which is the reason why you don't have access to the customizer nor the ability to create custom templates.

So, right now your options are:

- Upgrade your current plan to gain access to the customizer so you can add your own CSS rules and even use custom themes/plugins, or
- [Migrate your site to a self-hosted WordPress site](https://move.wordpress.com/) and get full control over the code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Inspect tool to find out the CSS classes used by your theme to define the content area.

Once you have found the CSS classes you can apply CSS in order to adjust it’s width to 100%. An example could be the following CSS code. However, please note that the class you have to use depends on your theme:

```
.content-area {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: OP said they don't have access to CSS though, so apparently they can't add any custom CSS rules to the site.

Comment: why shouldn't you have access to CSS on a WordPress site? Either enqueue a new stylesheet in functions.php or add plugin to handle extra CSS - There is plenty of solutions out there.

Comment: OP is hosting their website on **wordpress.com**, it's not a self-hosted WordPress site. Since OP is using the Free plan, they don't have access to "customization" options (see [wordpress.com plans comparison](https://wordpress.com/pricing/) for more details) so they're basically out of luck. They either upgrade their plan or migrate their site to a self-hosted WordPress solution.

Comment: @cabrerahector you might as well post that as the answer